# importing likelihoods fails

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, gaussian-process, gpytorch

I am trying to get in touch with Gaussian Process Classification and try to reproduce the example from https://docs.gpytorch.ai/en/stable/examples/01_Exact_GPs/GP_Regression_on_Classification_Labels.html

Following their code, I want to import the Dirichlet Classification Likelihood by

```
from gpytorch.likelihoods import DirichletClassificationLikelihood
```

However, this seems not to work, and I get the Error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'DirichletClassificationLikelihood' 
from 'gpytorch.likelihoods' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/
lib/python3.8/site-packages/gpytorch/likelihoods/__init__.py)
```

also other likelihoods as FixedNoiseGaussianLikelihood does not work.

I tried to reinstall GPyTorch in Conda, which did not help.
**but** importing i.e GaussianLikelihood works without problems. Did somebody had similar problems, or knows how to solve this Error?

**EDIT:** It only does not work for Jupyter Notebook.

Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

The paths of Jupyter Notebook did not include the new updated library. After updating paths to the wanted folder by

```
import sys
sys.paths.append("....")
```

it worked nice.

Best